# jinja2 render string multiple lines - expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, jinja2

a.py

```
test7 = (
    '{{ execution_date.in_tz("Asia/Seoul").subtract(hours=1)'
    '.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") }}'
)
```

main.py

```
import jinja2
import pathlib
import pendulum


context = {
    'logical_date': pendulum.now(),
    'execution_date': pendulum.now(),

}
path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent
filename = 'a.py'

jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(path),
)
rendered = jinja_env.get_template('temp/'+filename).render(context)
print(rendered)
```

error occurs: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'

How can I render multi lines?

This form is expected: 2023-09-24 23:04:22